# Adding Empty Rows

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to give the user an ability to add rows. i can't figure out what control to use to accomplish this.

for example

first row with empty text boxes is always visible:

```
    [first name] [last name] [middle name] 
    add more button
```

the add more button should create an other empty first,last, middle textbox row.

i have a submit button on the bottom that will validate and populate everything.... similarly if there is already data, accourding number of rows should be populated with data, with an empty textbox field on the bottom with an add more button....

hope i explained it ok...

any guidance would be appreciated.

i've already tried using a repeater and a gridview, but i can't figure out how to show and add empty rows of data...

i'm doing it in VB.NET

Comment: So, is this WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET WebForms, or...?

Comment: I'm assuming that you are using ASP.Net when you are talking about repeaters and gridViews.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate your Textboxes manually, for example as usercontrol to encapsulate them and the validation(but of course this is also possible with repeaters and gridviews):

ASCX of the usercontrol:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="NameControls.ascx.vb" Inherits="AJAXEnabledWebApplication1.NameControls" %>
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFirstName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxtFirstName" ErrorMessage="Enter firstname" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TxtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqLastName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxtLastName" ErrorMessage="Enter lastname" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TxtMiddleName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqMiddleName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxtMiddleName" ErrorMessage="Enter middlename" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Codebehind of the userControl:

```
Public Partial Class NameControls
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Public Property FirstName() As String
        Get
            Return Me.TxtFirstName.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.TxtFirstName.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property MiddleName() As String
        Get
            Return Me.TxtMiddleName.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.TxtMiddleName.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property LastName() As String
        Get
            Return Me.TxtLastName.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.TxtLastName.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property FirstNameRequired() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me.ReqFirstName.Enabled
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            Me.ReqFirstName.Enabled = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property MiddleNameRequired() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me.ReqMiddleName.Enabled
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            Me.ReqMiddleName.Enabled = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property LastNameRequired() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me.ReqLastName.Enabled
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            Me.ReqLastName.Enabled = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

ASPX of the testpage:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="DyntextBoxes.aspx.vb" Inherits="AJAXEnabledWebApplication1.DyntextBoxes" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>DyntextBoxes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DdlAddRow" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" >
                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="select to add" Selected="True" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="2" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="3" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="4" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="5" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="6" />
                </asp:DropDownList><br />
    <asp:placeholder ID="Placeholder1" runat="server" >
    </asp:placeholder> 
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonSave" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="100px"  />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Codebehind of the Testpage:

```
Public Partial Class DyntextBoxes
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Property RowCount() As Int32
        Get
            If ViewState("RowCount") Is Nothing Then
                ViewState("RowCount") = 0
            End If
            Return DirectCast(ViewState("RowCount"), Int32)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Int32)
            ViewState("RowCount") = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub DyntextBoxes_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        addRows(RowCount)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DdlAddRow.SelectedIndexChanged
        If DdlAddRow.SelectedValue <> "-1" Then
            Dim count As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(DdlAddRow.SelectedValue)
            addRows(count)
            RowCount += count
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub addRows(ByVal count As Int32)
        For i As Int32 = Me.Placeholder1.Controls.Count To (Me.Placeholder1.Controls.Count + count - 1)
            Dim nameControl As NameControls = DirectCast(LoadControl("NameControls.ascx"), NameControls)
            nameControl.ID = "nameControl_" & i
            nameControl.FirstNameRequired = True
            nameControl.MiddleNameRequired = False
            nameControl.LastNameRequired = True
            Me.Placeholder1.Controls.Add(nameControl)
            Me.Placeholder1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br />"))
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonSave.Click
        For i As Int32 = 0 To RowCount - 1
            Dim nameControl As NameControls = DirectCast(Me.PlaceHolder1.FindControl("nameControl_" & i), NameControls)
            'Do what you whant with it'
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```